# c# winform application sql exception

Tags: c#, sql, connection

I have created a windows application and the sql server is hosted in a server and I connect using webconfig.

Have created installer for it, works fine for me.

But when someone else outside the network tries it will get an error with sql connection.

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user <-- i used to get this too but since adding the correct username and pass to config it is fine for me

Comment: can you share your connection string

Comment: Its not just config files, you have to make sure that those users actually have the permission to your SQL Server.

Comment: but that means if 10 users using my app i need to add 10 users to sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question as it is now is way to vague to give a proper answer. Here's an msdn link with information about troubleshooting sql server connectivity issues:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156468.aspx